# Why doesn't Javascript let me close up my function?

Tags: javascript

I dunno guys, this is a really weird one, but I might just be making a simple mistake and not even realizing it.

I'm *sort of* a newbie to Javascript, so I'm attempting to write a script that gets content from a PHP script (which returns only a number) and write that data to a div... but Javascript had other ideas. I'm testing on Chrome on Mac OS X, although it doesn't work on Safari either.

The following block is giving me problems:

```
function getContent() {
 window.setInterval(function () {
  $.get("get.php", function (data) {
   $('#img').slideUp();
   $('#div').html(data);
   $('#div').slideDown();
  }
 }
}
```

Which is failing with:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

on line `51`, or line `8`, for the purposes of this example.

Does anyone know why it would fail like this? Don't I need to close the brackets I open?

Comment: IMHO Your indentation is too small, making it difficult to notice the obvious missing `)` char. I prefer to indent it to at least two spaces. But that is just me.

Comment: Sorry... it just came out like that. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your curly braces are OK, but you're missing a few parentheses:

```
function getContent() {
 window.setInterval(function () {
  $.get("get.php", function (data) {
   $('#img').slideUp();
   $('#div').html(data);
   $('#div').slideDown();
  }); //get - end statement
 }, 4000); // setInterval - need another parameter, end statement
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not closing the parentheses for your function calls.  As Kobi said, you also need a third parameter for `setInterval`.

```
function getContent() {
 window.setInterval(function () {
  $.get("get.php", function (data) {
   $('#img').slideUp();
   $('#div').html(data);
   $('#div').slideDown();
  });
 }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The window.setInterval function has a following syntax:

```
window.setInterval(functionRef, timeout);
```

In your case the `setInterval` and `$.get()` function call are missing the closing parentheses `)`. It would be clear for you to write this in the following way:

```
function getContent() {
  // success handler
  var success = function() {
    // declare the function first as "changeUI"
    var changeUI = function() {
      $('#img').slideUp();
      $('#div').html(data);
      $('#div').slideDown();
    };
    // call the setInterval passing the function
    window.setInterval(changeUI, 2000);
  };

  // get the resource and call the "success" function on successful response
  $.get("get.php", success);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your window.setInterval is missing a ) after the } on the second to last line